# predict missing values using rxpredict

Tags: r

I am trying to do predictions using linear model, consider a dataset with 2 columns and following data (1,1)(2,.5),(3,3),(4,5),(5,5,5)(6,7)(8,8)(9,9)(10,10) .. I can fit linear model as

```
lm <- rxlinMod(col1~col2, data=test)
```

and then run rxpredict as

```
pd <- rxPredict(lm,data=test)
```

given the result of `rxpredict`, how can I now find the value of `col2` where `col1` value is not available, example what will be the value of `col2` if `col1` is 7.

**Update:**
Package is revoscaler

data

```
col1,col2
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
8,8
9,9
10,10

infile <- file.path("C:/R-Spark", "test.csv")
test <- rxImport(infile)
library(rpart)

lm <- rxLinMod(col1 ~ col2, data = test)
rxPredict(lm,data = test)
```

Computation time: 0.003 seconds.

output

```
> rxPredict(lm,data = test)
Rows Read: 10, Total Rows Processed: 10, Total Chunk Time: 0.002 seconds 
   col1_Pred
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
6          6
7          7
8          8
9          9
10        10
```

question:
Now if I want to get the predicted value of only 7 how can I filter the data from the rxpredict output

Comment: Please show a reproducible example and the package name (RevoScaleR?)

Comment: You can't use a model to predict y given x, to predict x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try answering your question using different data, to avoid confusion when referring to the values of `col1`, `col2` or the data frame row indexes.

So, let's assume that

```
test <- data.frame(col1=seq(20,200,20), col2=seq(10,100,10))
```

`test` looks like this:

```
test
   col1 col2
1    20   10
2    40   20
3    60   30
4    80   40
5   100   50
6   120   60
7   140   70
8   160   80
9   180   90
10  200  100
```

now:

```
lm <- rxLinMod(col1~col2, data=test)
pd <- rxPredict(lm,data=test)
```

so

```
pd
   col1_Pred
1         20
2         40
3         60
4         80
5        100
6        120
7        140
8        160
9        180
10       200
```

Now, if you wish the predicted `col1` value when `col2 = 70` in your `test` data.frame (the data.frame used when calling `rxPredict`). You can do the following:

```
pd$col1_Pred[which(test$col2 == 70)]
[1] 140
```

Just to clarify, imagine you want to use the same linear model `lm` with new input data `test2`:

```
test2 <- data.frame(col2=c(15, 25, 35))

test2
  col2
1   15
2   25
3   35
```

Now:

```
pd2 <- rxPredict(lm,data=test2)

pd2
  col1_Pred
1        30
2        50
3        70
```

If you wish to single out the predicted `col1` value for `col2 = 25` in `test2`:

```
pd2$col1_Pred[which(test2$col2 == 25)]
[1] 50
```